# Change Shell script variable value inside AWK conditional block

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I want to update mystatus shell variable to new value inside my awk code.
     but I guess the syntax isn't right,
     also I have tried declare or eval , but nothing works
     hi please help me with this

my code:

```
   mystatus="resolved" -- shell variable
   awk 'BEGIN { print "<table>" } -- awk code to write in new file
   {
   print "<tr><td>" $1 "</td><td>" $2 "</td><tr>" 
   if ($1=="stopped") mystatus="problem" -- change shell variable value
   }
   END   { print "</table>" }' filestats.txt > email.html
   echo $mystatus -- variabe value not getting changed.
```

Comment: You can't change shell variable in that manner. Write it to a file in awk and read it to a variable in shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (untested):

```
mystatus="resolved"                         # shell variable
awk '
BEGIN { print "<table>" }                   # awk code to write in new file
{
    print "<tr><td>" $1 "</td><td>" $2 "</td><tr>" 
    if ($1=="stopped") {
        mystatus="mystatus.txt"
        print "problem" > mystatus          # write to a file instead
        close(mystatus)
    } # I WAS MISSING I WAS MISSING I WAS MISSING I WAS MISSING I WAS MISSING 
}
END   { print "</table>" }' filestats.txt > email.html
read mystatus < mystatus.txt                # read the status from the file
echo $mystatus                              # variabe value not getting changed.
```

Some bash purist could comment if this is any way to read from a file to a variable?

Comment: james: getting error for the above code
`
                            END{ print "</table>" }
awk: cmd. line:8: ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:9: END{ print "</table>" }
awk: cmd. line:9:                               ^ unexpected newline or end of string`

Comment: One `}` was missing.

Comment: no buddy ! the code executed well, but  mystatus.txt was not created !

Comment: Well, this works fine: `awk 'BEGIN{mystatus="mystatus.txt";print "problem" > mystatus;close(mystatus)}'` so I'd assume that your code never reaches that part of the program.

Comment: thanks james , it worked, really sorry for the previous comment! I am new toAWK